# Convert e.key to char

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Is there any way to convert `e.Key` to `char` in `Textbox` `keyDown` event in `Windows 8` store app?

Here is my code:

```
private void OnTextBoxKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    EcgStatementText.Text = (e.Key); // We should convert e.Key to chars
}
```

Comment: Regarding the Shift, do you want to get only the Shift Key or another key pressed using the shift modifier ?

Comment: I need another key press also.e.g (*,% ..)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
string result = ((Char)e.Key).ToString();
```

If you want to get Numberpad values take a look at this question: [How do I convert a "Keys" enum value to an "int" character in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769529/how-do-i-convert-a-keys-enum-value-to-an-int-character-in-c) :

Comment: How to avoid special char(*,%,^..) in keydown event?

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick,

```
var foo = ((Char)e.Key).ToString();
```